# py2app failure to launch with no significant log in the system console

Tags: python, python-3.x, py2app

I am trying to build an app with py2app and ... well it's not really working as expected.

[image: Console errors]

Here is my Pipfile:

```
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[dev-packages]

[packages]
paver = "*"
pillow = "*"
tk = "*"
pytest = "*"
py2app = "*"

[requires]
python_version = "3.7"
```

Other system information :

- Mac OS 10.13.6
- The app is also using tkdnd2.8

I have tried to put logs in the execution code, prior to any import. They are not called.

Answer (score 1):

So ... it turns out I was actually having problems in my code, but this does not make a relevant and informative answer for whoever comes after.

Once your `.app` is mad, you can run `./MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp` to execute the app from the terminal ... and the magic will happen, you will see the output of your execution. This is much better than the cryptic output displayed in the question.

A few extra advices, do not run this from a location or from an environment where your Python was tweaked ; because your current `PYTHON_PATH` will be used.